# View tag description on page

Tags: php, loop, tags, description

Everything works except tag description.
Could you help?

```
<?php while($my_Property->have_posts()) : $my_Property->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="ListaP" style="width:32%; display: inline-block;">
        <div class="Lista">
            <h4><?php the_title(''); ?></h4>
            <div class="thumbnail lista"
            <p class="propertyID" style="font-weight:600;">ID: <?php $post_url = get_the_ID($post_id); echo $post_url; ?></p>
            <p class="opisOdAgenta">ADRES: <?php the_field('deal_title'); ?></p>
            <p class="adresAgent">NOTATKI/UWAGI/: <?php the_field('deal_detail'); ?></p>
            <p class="klientWlasciciel">KTO PROWADZI: <?php the_author(); ?></p> 
            <p class="klientWlasciciel">WLASCICIEL: <?php echo 'Tag Description: ' . tag_description($tag_id); ?> </p>  //DOESNT WORK
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: what are your query parameters?

Comment: Michal did the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$tag_id` variable is not defined before use.  Try a test with a fixed value in there:

```
<p class="klientWlasciciel">WLASCICIEL: <?php echo 'Tag Description: ' . tag_description( '1' ); ?> </p>
```

... or test the default behavior which should be the current queried tag:

```
<p class="klientWlasciciel">WLASCICIEL: <?php echo 'Tag Description: ' . tag_description(); ?> </p>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/tag_description